# What does Axel Schuessler mean by "area word"?

Tags: terminology, etymology, chinese

My son's studying Chinese. His teacher asked  how 念 semantically appertains to its components 今心. I don't speak Chinese, and he had no idea. Then we resorted to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BF%B5#Etymology) that refers to  Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007), page 400. Pls see my red underline beneath.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it just means a word that exists (with variations, of course) in a geographical area that comprises several unrelated languages (a so-called _Sprachbund_), like an _areal feature_, but on a purely lexical level. There are lots of them in Northwest Europe as well, words that appear to be non-Indo-European, but appear in both Germanic and Celtic languages. 念 would then be the Chinese form of a word that exists in various local forms in languages throughout an area covering China down to Cambodia (and perhaps elsewhere).

Comment: Incidentally, if [the etymology for the Khmer word given here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%9E%85%E1%9F%86%E1%9E%8E%E1%9E%B6%E1%9F%86#Khmer) is correct, and it's an infixed form of a Khmer root _cam_, then it's a spurious cognate and seems unlikely to be related to a root shaped like *nem*.

Comment: But note that this is talking about the etymology of the **word**, which is different from the origin of the **character** (especially because the character 念 is used to represent two completely different words: ‘miss, think of’ and ‘read aloud’). The character itself is just a normal phono-semantic compound, with 今 providing the phonetic hint, 心 the semantic one – although 今 as a phonetic compound is quite diffuse, as you can see from the variation of pronunciations found in the list of other characters in the same phonetic series on the Wiktionary page.

Comment: If 念 really is a phonosemantic character (as stated in 說文解字), this would give some credence to this idea of a _Sprachbund_ word 'cognate' to Khmer ចំណាំ _camnam_, because its phonetic component 今 would have been *_krem_ in Old Chinese.

Comment: However, phonemic correspondences are unclear (*c vs *kr), although adding Austronesian reportedly gives as far south as [Javanese _angrem_ /ˈʔa.ŋrəm/](https://www.lotpublications.nl/Documents/542_fulltext.pdf) ("to brood, to stay in one place"). Also the Proto-Sino-Tibetan root [has already been reconstructed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Sino-Tibetan/s-njam) as *s-njam, [based on cognates in](https://stedt.berkeley.edu/~stedt-cgi/rootcanal.pl/etymon/5554) Tibetan སྙམ་པ _snyam.pa_ ("to think/mind"), Darang/Digaro/Deng _ním_ ("brain"), and Kiranti _nyam_ ("brain").

Comment: Expanding on what @JanusBahsJacquet said, I think the term for this type of word is Wanderwort, which, like Sprachbund, is taken from German.

Comment: @AaronQuitta A Wanderwort is a somewhat different thing. Wanderwörter are words that _spread_ from a particular source, often through trade, and are loaned into other languages as they travel. They frequently have known etymologies that reveal a single point of origin (i.e., a single source language), but they can be spread to quite unrelated geographical areas. Areal words/features generally appear in multiple languages in the _same_ area, and it’s usually impossible to tell where they originated – many are assumed to be substrate words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is still incomplete!*

Chinese is grouped in the Sino-Tibetan language family as determined by experts on account of certain features that are unlikely to be coincidental, pointing to a deeper *genetic* relation. Khmer is in a different language family, whose stemming is contested because many affiliations are less than clear. South East Asian share many features that may have diffused horizontally through language contact. This is sometimes called a Sprachbund (from German *Sprache* "language, speech" + *Bund* "bond, federation", coined in reference to the Balkans Sprachbund).

Chinese research on the other hand has the practical advantage of a written tradition, attestation beginning with Oracle Bone Script sometime before the common era, dispersing widely and culminating in the first millenium in a dictionary for a courtly branch of this tradition, that is now called Shouwen, in which the author tried to categorize and etymologize characters. These etymologies are not always correct, current research shows, as they did not have the necessary depth, and they may be better thought of as memory aid. How traditional or, in a sense, correct those *folk etymologies* were is not clear. Anyway, this is likely what the teacher is asking for. That's different from an etymology for the spoken word.

For the Chinese and Khmer words to be "related" or not, as one comment puts it (@jogloran), the language families have to be related, in a technical sense, for vertical transmission along the branches of a family tree to occur. Schuessler does a priori not assume any such relation. Nevertheless, it's not entirely out of the question that the languages share some words. This tends to be a difficult topic, because it needs a framework in which language contact is possible.

An *area word* in this sense would simply mean that the word was common in an area of language contact. Diglossia, that is bilungualism with a dominant standard language in contrast to regional vernacular to various degrees of profficiency is said to be statistically more common than not. However, it's not said where this would have occurd. It's possible that Schuessler's book has an introduction outlining his basic assumptions, detailing which ones of these need to be understood as research problems in need of further investigation, but the choice of verbiage, ie. *area word*, might be arbitrary at that (and I do not have the book at hand nor any investment in this field).

If there is further research to be found in the more recent literature, or if it is enough to point out an acceptible derivation for only one half of the equation to rule out horizontal transmission (as @jogloran seems to suggest, prerequisite that transmission from Proto-Mon-Khmer to Chinese was out of the question).

For the sake of completeness  let's note that visual representation of an abstract concept like"to think of, remember, remind" is necessarily difficult, and that spatially and object information is prevalent in the mental space,